# Ubuntu 18.04: Earphones not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

### No sound via headphones (headset)

I've recently started using Ubuntu (Dual boot with Windows 10)
The earphone works on other devices/Windows without any issues.
I've even tried to not boot up with earphones plugged in.
Laptop: ASUS S56C
The internal speakers work fine.

**ALSA information** (alsa-info-script): https://hastebin.com/oyuvihecof.scala
**alsa-base.conf**: https://hastebin.com/azeqeroqid.pl

Comment: I don't think this question qualifies as a duplicate. I checked the duplicate thread, none of the solutions work for me, plus they are all for other version of Ubuntu. I think it's more important that this specific question is left open for ubuntu 18.04, in order to potentially get working answers.

Comment: Generally we don't have version specific Questions and Answers.  If an answer is specific to a version then we usually put as the first line the version of Ubuntu it is applicable for.

Answer (score 0):

Left mouse click on [sound icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCrUN.png) and select "sound settings".
There you can select proper output device and test it.

Comment: I have the same problem, it doesn't look like the headphones show up under devices, and the no sound comes out during the tests.

Answer (score -3):

Just you have to select the sound output, go to "settings" > "sound" > and select your headphones. 
As simple as that.